# how do I create Dummy Variables in RStudio? with numeric data?

Tags: rstudio, dummy-data

JOB
0 : unemployed/ unskilled  - non-resident
1 : unskilled - resident
2 : skilled employee / official
3 : management/ self-employed/highly qualified employee/ officer
HISTORY
0: no credits taken
1: all credits at this bank paid back duly 
2: existing credits paid back duly till now 
3: delay in paying off in the past
4: critical account

Comment: Please clarify your question.  What problem are you trying to solve?  How can R help you do that?

Comment: how do I create Dummy Variables in RStudio? with numeric data? To transfer JOB into JOB1, JOB2, JOB3 three dummy binary variables.

Answer (score 0):

First: RStudio is an IDE (Integrated Development Environment). You probably want to use R (the language/stat program that RStudio uses, but that can also be used independently).

Your question is very unclear but if (which I'm not sure of) you're looking for a way to use dummy variables in for example a regression model, you might instead consider a factor variable:

```
JOB <- factor(sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE), 
              levels= 0:3,
              labels = c("unemployed/ unskilled - non-resident",
                         "unskilled - resident",
                         "skilled employee / official",
                         "management/ self-employed/highly qualified employee/ officer"),
              ordered = TRUE
)
```

Wich will give you:

```
 [1] unskilled - resident                                        
 [2] unskilled - resident                                        
 [3] skilled employee / official                                 
 [4] skilled employee / official                                 
 [5] skilled employee / official                                 
 [6] unskilled - resident                                        
 [7] management/ self-employed/highly qualified employee/ officer
 [8] unskilled - resident                                        
 [9] skilled employee / official                                 
[10] management/ self-employed/highly qualified employee/ officer
4 Levels: unemployed/ unskilled - non-resident < unskilled - resident < ... < management/ self-employed/highly qualified employee/ officer
```

and similar for HISTORY.